# "Failed to send periodic counter updates" error inside job worker

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

For a weird reason and only for the past few days, Dataflow doesn't seem to be able to send step logs or update UI step counters.

I presume the reason is purely an IAM issue, but even when using a fresh new project the issue is still there.

A notable thing to say is that my job (a custom pubsub > bigquery pipeline) is still being executed perfectly.

Here is the payload/trace found in Stackdriver on the `worker` level :

```
{
 insertId:  "6719480855170687722:477955:0:122647"  
 jsonPayload: {
  exception:  "com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "(2efb88076acae577): Failed to publish the result of the work update. Causes: (2efb88076acae982): Could not update work; user does not have write access to project: [...]",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "(2efb88076acae577): Failed to publish the result of the work update. Causes: (2efb88076acae982): Could not update work; user does not have write access to project: [...]",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.runners.worker.DataflowWorkUnitClient.reportWorkItemStatus(DataflowWorkUnitClient.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.sendWorkerUpdatesToDataflowService(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1163)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.reportPeriodicWorkerUpdates(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1122)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$5.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:450)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
"   
  job:  "2017-10-01_09_46_35-1778703197096293569"   
  logger:  "com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker"   
  message:  "Failed to send periodic counter updates"   
  thread:  "33"   
  work:  "<nil>"   
  worker:  "ingest-paywall-seen-10010946-b8e5-harness-bnt1"   
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "6719480855170687722"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "ingest-paywall-seen-10010946-b8e5-harness-bnt1"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_type:  "instance"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id:  "2017-10-01_09_46_35-1778703197096293569"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name:  "ingest-paywall-seen"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/region:  "us-central1"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/[...]/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fworker"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2017-10-01T16:51:43.887618561Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id:  "2017-10-01_09_46_35-1778703197096293569"    
   job_name:  "ingest-paywall-seen"    
   project_id:  "[...]"    
   region:  "us-central1"    
   step_id:  ""    
  }
  type:  "dataflow_step"   
 }
 severity:  "WARNING"  
 timestamp:  "2017-10-01T16:51:24.024Z"  
}
```

I obviously checked for IAM to be sure everything was good, and my `@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com` identity seems to have the default role given when enabling the Dataflow API.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are these just transient warnings? Is your pipeline finishing successfully?

Comment: Every 10sec when a task is running, probably when Dataflow updates its sidebar counters. And yes, as stated in my question, my pipeline is executed perfectly from start to finish. It is more a practical issue than a blocking one tbh, I can live not having feedback from my pipelines, but my life could be better with :)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same problem. One weird thing is it's only when my pipeline is running in a European zone. It's okay and send counter when it's running in the US...

Comment: Nope :/ didn't try to run the pipeline in the US though. And since I didn't find any solution/answer/clue to this, I simply stopped trying to use Dataflow...